# Parametrization and Affine Varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

[image]

This is an exercise (exercise 3.3) question from the text "Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms" by Cox, Little, and O'Shea. I have question about part c.

Using Macaulay2 (web) I got the second elimination ideal $I_2=I\cap\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]=\langle x^2-yz\rangle$. I get this from the reduced Groebner basis of $$I=\langle x-uv,y-u^2,z-v^2\rangle$$ which is $GB=\{u^2-y,uv-x,ux-vy,uz-vx,v^2-z,x^2-yz\}$.

Now solving $x^2-yz=0$ we need $y,z$ to  have the same sign. But from $v^2-z=0$, that sign needs to be plus to be over $\mathbb{R}$. What is the answer to the last part of the question: as to which parametrization would cover the other "half."

Comment: Have you tried to draw these shapes? I think you might find it helpful.

Comment: @BernhardListing - There is a map of $k$-algebras $\phi: k[x,y,z] \rightarrow k[u,v]$ defined by $\phi(x):=u^2,\phi(y):=uv, \phi(z):=v^2$ (the variables $x,y$ are switched) with kernel $ker(\phi)=(xz-y^2)$, hence $Im(\phi):=k[u^2,uv,v^2] \cong k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2)$. It follows your parametrized algebraic set $S$ is contained in the irreducible surface $V(xz-y^2)$. This should answer question $a$.